# Angular - How to avoid redundant function calls in table cells?

Tags: angular, angular12, angular-material-table

I have to display a table for an array of objects. Each object has a few static properties which I always have to display and a list of dynamic properties. For each of those dynamic properties, I have to display three columns in the table. The class for those objects looks like this:

```
export class Job {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  data: JobData[];
}

export class JobData {
  id: number;
  value: number;
  minValue: number;
  maxValue: number;
}
```

In order to know which dynamic properties exist without iterating through the `data` of one of the objects, I can retrieve a list of all the `data` properties I can expect to find in each object. Each object in this list is an instance of this class:

```
export class DynamicProperty {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

As you can probably imagine, it gets a little bit complicated to generate the list of displayed columns in this situation. Here is how I do it in my component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { JobData, JobData, DynamicProperty } from "src/app/_models/job";

@Component({
  selector: "app-job-data",
  templateUrl: "./job-data.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./job-data.component.scss"],
})
export class JobDataComponent implements OnChanges {
  displayedColumns = [
    "id",
    "name",
  ];
  headerRowColumns = ["header-row-static-group"];
  headerColumns: string[] = [];
  jobColumns: string[] = [];

  @Input()
  jobs?: Job[];

  @Input()
  dynamicProperties?: DynamicProperty[];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.dynamicProperties.currentValue !== undefined) {
      this.addDynamicPropertyColumns();
    }
  }

  getDynamicPropertyById(id: string): DynamicProperty {
    return this.dynamicProperties.find((element) => {
      return element.id.toString() === id;
    });
  }

  getDataByDynamicPropertyId(job: Job, id: string): JobData {
    return job.data.find((element) => {
      return element.id.toString() === id;
    });
  }

  addDynamicPropertyColumns() {
    this.dynamicProperties.forEach((parameter) => {
      const id = parameter.id.toString();
      this.jobColumns.push("value" + id);
      this.jobColumns.push("minValue" + id);
      this.jobColumns.push("maxValue" + id);
      this.headerColumns.push(id);
    });

    this.displayedColumns = this.displayedColumns.concat(this.jobColumns);
    this.headerRowColumns = this.headerRowColumns.concat(this.headerColumns);
  }
}
```

While the static columns do not have a visible group above them, the dynamic properties are grouped so a header column is added for each of the three columns that are added for every dynamic property. This is done so the user can see that each of the three columns belong together.

Here is my HTML template for displaying the table:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="jobs">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-static-group">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="2"></th>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let headerColumn of headerColumns"
    matColumnDef="{{ headerColumn }}"
  >
    <ng-container
      *ngTemplateOutlet="
        template;
        context: {
          dynamicProperty: getDynamicPropertyById(headerColumn)
        }
      "
    ></ng-container>
    <ng-template #template let-dynamicProperty="dynamicProperty">
      <ng-container *ngIf="dynamicProperty !== undefined">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="3">
          {{ dynamicProperty.name }}
        </th>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="{{ 'value' + dynamicProperty.id }}">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Value</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            {{ getDataByDynamicPropertyId(element, headerColumn)?.value }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="{{ 'minValue' + dynamicProperty.id }}">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Min. Value</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            {{ getDataByDynamicPropertyId(element, headerColumn)?.minValue }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="{{ 'maxValue' + dynamicProperty.id }}">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Max. Value</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            {{ getDataByDynamicPropertyId(element, headerColumn)?.maxValue }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="headerRowColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

While this does work just fine, I do not think that it is very effective in terms of performance at all. For every of the three columns for a dynamic property, I have to call `getDataByDynamicPropertyId()` in order to get the `data` object from the element. I was not able to find any better solution yet because I do not have access to the `element` outside of the cell, as only in the cell I can access the element via `*matCellDef="let element"`.

My question is: Is there a better, more elegant way to do this? This feels to me like I was basically forced by Angular to come up with this "bad" solution, as many of the things I would have preferred to do simply do not seem to be possible (for example, accessing the `element` outside of the cell). If there is a better way to achieve the same thing as my solution does, please let me know. I would especially like to get rid of those redundant `getDataByDynamicPropertyId()` calls, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in your intuition that it's a performance loss to call a function in your template this way, because for each tick, each function call will be triggered again.

I think what you could do is to define a child element that would contain the td content :

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <my-child-td [element]="element" [headerColumn]="headerColumn" [getDataByDynamicPropertyId]="getDataByDynamicPropertyId"></my-child-td>
</td>
```

Then, in the child, you can call the function in ngOnChanges(), only when the element or headerColumn Inputs change, something like :

```
@Input() element;
@Input() headerColumn;
@Input() getDataByDynamicPropertyId: Function;

public myValue;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes['element'] || changes['headerColumn']) {
    this.myValue = this.getDataByDynamicPropertyId(this.element, this.headerColumn)
  }
}
```

It's even better if getDataByDynamicPropertyId is defined inside the child component itself (in case it's not needed elsewhere)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Could you explain what exactly such a child element is? I was under the impression that I cannot wrap a `td` around my three columns for each dynamic property because it would break the structure of my table. I do not want the three properties to be inside a single column/cell. Would three child elements inside the `td` behave the same like having three individual `td`s, or how exactly would that work?